# Membership operator: How to use "my_var" actual value in "my_struct->my_var"?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

In C, I have defined following `struct`:

```
typedef struct my_struct{
  int foo;
  my_struct* a;
  my_struct* b;
} my_struct;
```

Now, I have a variable `char my_var;` that holds either the value "a" or "b".

**Question:** How to access "`my_struct->my_var`" where `my_var` is considered as its actual value (i.e. either as the character `a` or `b`) rather than as the "string" `my_var`?

(Indeed, my compiler throws an error saying that there is no member "`my_var`" defined in the struct `my_struct`.)

Comment: You are perhaps trying to emulate a C++ feature, namely member pointers. You can always use a *normal* pointer and let it point to a member of a *particular* struct object, but that may not be what you want (you want a selector for a struct you can pass at run time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me point out that for indexing we usually use arrays ;-). IIUC, your use case implies that all members you want to be able to select through the character must be of the same type, here `my_struct *`. So define an array:

```
struct my_struct{
  int foo;
  my_struct* ptrs[255]; /* can index with any char */
};
```

Now you can happily index with characters:

```
struct my_struct *sP; 
/* initialize sP and *sP... */
struct my_struct *sMemP = sP->ptrs['a'];
```

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing built-in that does this. C has no run-time introspection of structure types; member names only exist at compile time.

You can use a conditional operator:

```
my_struct *x = my_var == 'a' ? my_struct->a : my_struct->b;
```

If the actual structure is more complicated (you only used 2 members as a simplified example in the question) you could use a lookup table:

```
struct offset_map {
    char name;
    size_t offset;
}[] = {
    {'a', offsetof(my_struct, a)},
    {'b', offsetof(my_struct, b)}
};
```

You can then write a function that loops through the table and returns the corresponding offset.

```
size_t get_offset(char name) {
    int size = sizeof(offset_map)/sizeof(*offset_map);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (offset_map[i].name == name) {
            return offset_map[i].offset;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

my_struct *x = (my_struct *)((char *)&my_struct + get_offset(my_var));
```

Comment: Good to know that it isn't possible. As I wanted to be "smart", I indeed defined each letter of the alphabet as a member of `my_struct`, and hoped to be able to "map" them. Yet it seems I won't avoid a switch statement!

Comment: @ebo I've updated it to show how to use a lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't transform a `char` variable into code.**

You need to check `my_var`'s value:

```
if (my_var == 'a')
  my_struct->a;
else if (my_var == 'b')
  my_struct->b;
else
  ; // Handle unexpected value?
```